# How to have admin user destroy other users? Devise CanCanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to have an admin user delete other users. When i try to delete another users registration path it deletes the admin. Ive seen a few other posts with the same issue but have not been able to replicate it.

This is all_users.html.erb :

```
    <h2 class="admin">All Users</h2>

    <table class="table table-striped">
 <tbody>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Cell Phone</th>
      <th>Login Method</th>
      <th>Delete User</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tr>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<td><%= user.first_name %></td>
<td><%= user.last_name %></td>
<td><%= user.cell_phone %></td>
<td><%= user.sprovider %></td>
<td><%= link_to user_registration_path, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, method: :delete do%>
  <span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span>
  <% end %></td>
</tr>
  <% end %>
    </tbody>
      </table>
```

Why is the current_user (the admin) being deleted instead of the user who i am calling the delete method on?

Comment: Why `user_registration_path` has method delete? Could you please post the corresponding controller action for delete?

Comment: If you are using default **Devise** routes, then your link should be: `link_to user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do`

Comment: @JustinLicata i tried that but its giving me an undefined method user_path...

Comment: Sorry, your path should be `registration_path(user)`, instead of `user`.

Comment: Yeah ive tried that before, and it does the same thing. It deletes the current user(which is the admin) and not the user i called the delete method on...

Comment: agh, yes you are definitely correct there. Devise has an excellent wiki with examples, perhaps this one will guide you- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-Users-with-an-Admin-Role-(CanCan-method)

Comment: I came across that link earlier, and it does not help much. Thank you though

Comment: @IS04 Yeah i spent a good about of time looking at the exact post, but it didnt work for me...

Comment: what do you mean `didin't work for me`? you should create own `action/routes` for destroying user. If your `action/routes` doesn't work properly, so just add your code to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using Devise as the auth method for your users. Although devise will create routes for authentication / registration (and even a self account descruction) it does not create the regular REST controller for the User model.

I would suggest to create a new UsersController, with the regular index, show, delete, update, create, etc., as well as the regular route

```
resources :users
```

and use that controller for deleting other users. That way you could have a proper

```
<%= link_to @user, method: :delete, confirm: 'Are You Sure?' %>
```